# Azure ActiveDirectory Graph API GraphClient not returning AD Groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, single-sign-on, asp.net-identity, adfs

I want to retrieve a User's Group information from Azure AD.

Using the following Graph API packages to achieve this

- Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
- Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.13.112191810

I am able to successfully retrieve Users information from the Azure Graph API.

But when I run this method to retrieve a User's groups, Fiddler shows a successful HTTP 200 response with JSON fragment containing group information however the method itself does not return with the IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerable<string> groups = user.GetMemberGroupsAsync(false).Result.ToList();
```

The code doesn't seem to return from this async request.

The resulting experience is blank page while the authentication pipeline gets stuck.

Full code

```
public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true &&
            _authorizationService.IdentityRegistered(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name))
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }

        _authorizationService.AddClaimsToIdentity(((ClaimsIdentity) incomingPrincipal.Identity));

        Claim tenantClaim = incomingPrincipal.FindFirst(TenantIdClaim);

        if (tenantClaim == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Tenant claim not available, role authentication is not supported");
        }

        string tenantId = tenantClaim.Value;
        string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _aadInstance, _tenant);
        Uri servicePointUri = new Uri("https://graph.windows.net");
        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(_clientId, _password);

        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);
        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireToken(servicePointUri.ToString(), clientCredential);
        Token = result.AccessToken;

        ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient =
            new ActiveDirectoryClient(new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId),
                async () => await AcquireTokenAsync());

       IUser user = activeDirectoryClient
           .Users
           .Where(x => x.UserPrincipalName.Equals(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name))
           .ExecuteAsync()
           .Result
           .CurrentPage
           .ToList()
           .FirstOrDefault();

        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unknown User.");
        }          

       IEnumerable<string> groups = user.GetMemberGroupsAsync(false).Result.ToList();


        return incomingPrincipal;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem. My code is working after changing it according to documentation
https://github.com/AzureADSamples/ConsoleApp-GraphAPI-DotNet

```
        IUserFetcher retrievedUserFetcher = (User) user;
        IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = retrievedUserFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync().Result;
        do {
            List<IDirectoryObject> directoryObjects = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
            foreach (IDirectoryObject directoryObject in directoryObjects) {
                if (directoryObject is Group) {
                    Group group = directoryObject as Group;
                    ((ClaimsIdentity)incomingPrincipal.Identity).AddClaim(
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.DisplayName, ClaimValueTypes.String, "GRAPH"));
                }
            }
            pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        } while (pagedCollection != null && pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable);
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Note however the solution above using `memberOf` is a intransitive list, i.e. direct members only. Where `getMemberGroups` function that is not working is a transitive. You would need to iterate each groups groups also. From the [doco](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations#UserFunctions) "You can call the getMemberGroups function to return all the groups that the user is a member of. The check is transitive, unlike reading the memberOf navigation property, which returns only the groups that the user is a direct member of."

Comment: I have the same issue with most of my calls I tried to do with this library. It hangs all the time, even though Fiddler shows that a successful request has been made.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable, `string groups = user.GetMemberGroupsAsync(false).Result.ToList()` doesn't work since the result is not of type IEnumerable, string.

```
IEnumerable<string> groups = await user.GetMemberGroupsAsync(false);
```

Above code would return the correct type.