# Get member groups in Azure Graph API library hangs

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient version 2.1.1.0 to get groups that my user belongs to.
Method call is like this:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(
                                        new Uri(GraphUrl),
                                        async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());

IEnumerable<string> groups = GetGroupsAsync(activeDirectoryClient, "currentUserObjectId").Result;

private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetGroupsAsync(ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient, string currentUserObjectId )
{
    return await activeDirectoryClient.Users.GetByObjectId(currentUserObjectId).GetMemberGroupsAsync(true);

}

private static async Task<string> GetAppTokenAsync()
{
            var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(ServiceRoot);
            var token = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(GraphUrl,new ClientCredential("clientId", "clientSecret"));
            return token.AccessToken;
}
```

However the method hangs even though in Fiddler I see that the request has succedeed and contains correct groups.

My question is duplicate of [Azure ActiveDirectory Graph API GraphClient not returning AD Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27670394/159057). A workaround exists but not a explanation why the method does not work.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more in your example?(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) It would be good to see the code that is invoking this method.

Comment: I added calling method to the example

Answer (score 0):

If indeed your ServiceRoot value is the same for your instantiation of ActiveDirectoryClient and for your call to AuthenticationContext, that could be the source of your problem.

ActiveDirectoryClient should be instantiated with https://graph.windows.net/

AuthenticationContext should be called with
https://login.microsoftonline.com/

Though that wouldn't manifest itself in the method hanging nor a successful request, that was the only change I had to make to your code for it to work for me, otherwise it would return with a Not Found error.

Comment: I fixed the URLs in the snippet and also added a link to duplicate question. URLs are correct in my real code as I see correct HTTP messages in Fiddler. Do you think maybe calling Result on the method may be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues with the Graph Api library when using the Result property, try changing your call to this:-

```
IEnumerable<string> groups = await GetGroupsAsync(activeDirectoryClient, "currentUserObjectId");
```